# yii ErrorHandler with different view layout in a module

Tags: yii, yii-modules

I have a custom module that uses it's own set of layout/views. However for the errors I want to use the default site layout and view. In my module I'm setting the `errorHandler` `errorAction` to `site/error`

```
class AdminModule extends CWebModule {

    public function init() {
        $this->setImport(array(
            'admin.models.*',
            'admin.components.*',
        ));

        Yii::app()->setComponents(array(
            'errorHandler'=>array('errorAction'=>'site/error'),
        ));

        $this->layout = 'admin';
    }


    public function beforeControllerAction($controller, $action) {
        if(parent::beforeControllerAction($controller, $action)) {
            $controller->layout = $this->layout;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

However it's still using the admin layout and I want it to use the default layout. How do I overwrite it just for the error action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `actionError()` of `SiteController` Just add the default layout name

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{

public function actionError()
    {
        $this->layout='defaultLayoutName';
           //rest of the code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: That kind of works, it's using the layout, but because I'm using bootstrap in the `admin` component the css is over written by bootstrap.css